# React-native нативный модуль с вложенными view

Tags: java, swift, kotlin, objective-c, react-native

Мне необходимо сделать ui нативный модуль react-native для ios и android, содержащий вложенные друг в друга view:

```
+-----------------------+
|  Wrapper native view  |
| +--------------------+|
| | Inner native view  ||
| | +-----------------+||
| | |  React childs   |||
| | +-----------------+||
| +--------------------+|
+-----------------------+
```

**Внешний view должен содержать внутренний view в котором, в свою очередь, должны рендерится react компоненты.**

Примеров с такой компоновкой я не встречал. Попадалась только следующая структура:
Точка входа Manager (android - ViewGroupManager, ios - RCTViewManager) из которого создается один единственный view (android - ReactViewGroup, ios - RCTView) внутри которого рендерятся react компоненты. Каким образом мне сделать желаемое, как создать дополнительный вложенный view?

Буду благодарен примерам на swift/kotlin, с objective-c/java тоже разберусь.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте свой собственный менеджер для каждого из нативных `View`.Для ios нужно создать `RCTViewManager` и `RCTView`, который использует вложенный `UIView`. Для android вам нужно создать `ViewGroupManager` и `ReactViewGroup`.
пример для ios:

```
class InnerNativeView: RCTView {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // Код для инициализации вложенного UIView
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}

@objc(InnerNativeViewManager)
class InnerNativeViewManager: RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return InnerNativeView()
  }
}
```

Потом надо регистрировать `InnerNativeViewManager` в JavaScript коде:

```
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

const InnerNativeView = requireNativeComponent('InnerNativeView', null);

// Использование InnerNativeView в вашем компоненте
<InnerNativeView>
  {/* Ваши React-компоненты */}
</InnerNativeView>
```

Еще можно использ. библиотеку с помощью `npm` или `yarn`:

```
npm install react-native-reanimated
```

Затем возьмите `Animated.View`, чтобы создать нативный `View` и использовать его в качестве контейнера для ваших React-компонентов:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

function WrapperNativeView() {
  return (
    <Animated.View>
      <View>
        <Text>Inner Native View</Text>
      </View>
      {/* Ваши React-компоненты */}
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

Еще решение -это Modal компонент:

```
import { View, Modal } from 'react-native';

function WrapperNativeView() {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
        <Text>Open Modal</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(false);
        }}>
        <View>
          <Text>Inner Native View</Text>
          {/* Ваши React-компоненты */}
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

P.S. Дополняю ответ в соответствии с замечанием. я предлагаю вам использовать существующую структуру с `Manager` и единственным `View`, но добавить еще один слой вложенности внутри этого `View`.

Для этого, вам необходимо создать новый класс нативного кода, который будет расширять существующий класс `View` (iOS: `RCTView`, Android: `ReactViewGroup`) и добавлять в него дополнительный вложенный `View`. Затем, вам нужно будет обновить Manager для использования этого нового класса `View` вместо стандартного.

На iOS:

```
// Создание нового класса для нативного View
class InnerNativeView: RCTView {
    // Добавление вложенного View
    let innerView: UIView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(innerView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// Обновление Manager для использования нового View
@objc(InnerNativeViewManager)
class InnerNativeViewManager: RCTViewManager {
    override func view() -> UIView! {
        return InnerNativeView()
    }
}
```

На Android:

```
// Создание нового класса для нативного View
public class InnerNativeView extends ReactViewGroup {
    // Добавление вложенного View
    private View innerView;

    public InnerNativeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        innerView = new View(context);
        addView(innerView);
    }
}

// Обновление Manager для использования нового View
public class InnerNativeViewManager extends ViewGroupManager<InnerNativeView> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "InnerNativeView";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected InnerNativeView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new InnerNativeView(reactContext);
    }
}
```

В данном примере мы создаем класс `InnerNativeView` на нативном уровне, который расширяет существующий класс `View` и добавляет в него дополнительный вложенный `View`. Затем мы обновляем `Manager` для использования этого нового класса `View` вместо стандартного.

Comment: Такой вариант мне увы не подойдет, мне необходимо будет взаимодействовать как с внешним view, так и с внутренним и содержащимися в нем react childs из нативного кода. Мне просто нужно сделать два вложенных дуг в друга нативных view и определить в каком месте внутреннего view будут рендерится react childs.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, это уже более похоже на то что я хотел, но как теперь рендерить children компонента внутри innerView? Они все равно продолжают рендерится во внешнем view.

Comment: В ios разобрался как рендерить children, там надо просто переопределить метод didUpdateReactSubviews. А как быть в android?